# Javascript boolean logic error

Tags: javascript, boolean

My code:

```
var old = localStorage.getItem('GotoBeginning');
console.log("old is "+ old);
if (old===true) {
  console.log("Returning true");
  $("#gobeg").prop('checked', true);
  return true;
} else {
  console.log("Returning false");
  $("#gobeg").prop('checked', false);
  return false;
}
```

The value in localStorage for GotoBeginning is true.
My console.log shows:

```
old is true
Returning false
```

I expected the following output:

```
old is true
Returning true
```

Answer (score 2):

The storage api in the browser only stores strings. This should work:

```
if (old === 'true') {
//          ^    ^

} else {

}
```

As mentioned in a comment by IrkenInvader, you can extract the proper type like so:

```
var old = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('GotoBeginning'))
// now old will be a proper boolean so this will work
if (old) {

} else {

}
```

Comment: or use `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('GotoBeginning'));`

Comment: And also try to:  `console.log('retrievedObject: ', JSON.parse(old));`